# request level global variables for each websocket connection in nodejs (res.locals alternative for websockets)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to make some global variables in io.use method of socket io server side library. the purpose is to have variables that are available all throughout the request lifecycle (whatever request means in terms of websockets). I am using express framework and socket.io library. The snippet is as follows :-

```
io.use(function(socket, next) {
  _io = io;
  _sid = socket.id;
  _varName = socket.handshake.query.varName;
  next();
});
```

What I am trying to have is something like res.locals for websockets i.e. global variables scoped to each individual websocket connection.

**the problem that I am facing using above snippet is that these variables hold value for the last received request and is not reliable across multiple requests.**

**also, is io.use the best place to do jwt verification if I want to do jwt based auth on each incoming message?**

Comment: `also,` questions contain only one question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global variables got very limited usecases. This isnt one. SocketIO allows you to put all your handlers into the socket callback. Thats quite good as it allows you to closure the variables you want:

```
io.on("connection", function(socket, next) {
  var sid = socket.id;
  var varName = socket.handshake.query.varName;

  socket.on("message", function(){
    console.log(varName);
  });

  //...
});
```

If thats not an option then might invent your own locals object:

```
io.use(function(socket, next) {
  socket.locals = {
     sid: socket.id,
     varName: socket.handshake.query.varName
  };
  next();
});
```

... However i dont see any sense in copying properties that are part of the socket anyway.